# How to create symbolic link in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, symbolic-link

I have a bug in my steam installation that requires me to create a symbolic link, this is the command i'm using:

```
ln -s SteamApps steamapps
```

I get this error message: failed to create symbolic link: Read-only file system. I looked through forums and this seems to be an error related to virtual machines, however I'm not using a virtual machine.

Comment: `sudo ln -s SteamApps steamapps`

Comment: @cmak.fr, may not work: error would have been "permission denied". Here, we might indeed be dealing with some kind of a read only file system, but that is to the specialists of Steam to find out. Or maybe it is a mounted Snap?

Comment: The filesystem is readonly, which filesystem we are talking a linux or a windows? Edit your question and show `findmnt` please

Comment: I found that out that my filesystem was corrupted, that was the cause of the error. I fixed it using efsck. Thanks everyone for your input. I had a dual boot installation, seems like copying files from a windows partition to a linux one caused the corruption but I may be wrong, because I used to do that before without any issues.